# xml parsing with python, more than 1 depth

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a very big xml file and would like to get some records based on childnode text. Let's see i have a xml below and i would like to get price value if item taste is good. (good)
I tried to use minidom and ET.ElementTree but couldn't find a proper method.

I would like to do something like that;

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
dom = parse( "file.xml" )
for node in dom.getElementsByTagName('food'):
    node_child=node.getAttribute('description')
       taste=node_child.getAttribute('taste')
       if taste=='good':
          price=node.getAttribute('price')
```

Any idea?

```
<breakfast_menu>
 <food>
  <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>$5.95</price>
  <description>
   <taste>good</taste>
   <sight>bad</sight>
 </description>
 <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
 <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
 <price>$7.95</price>
 <description>
   <taste>bad</taste>
   <sight>bad</sight>
 </description>
 <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
 <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
 <price>$8.95</price>
 <description>
  <taste>good</taste>
  <sight>good</sight>
 </description>
 <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
 <name>French Toast</name>
 <price>$4.50</price>
 <description>
   <taste>good</taste>
   <sight>bad</sight>
 </description>
 <calories>600</calories>
</food>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the example code you have provided? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to parse it.

**Code:**

```
from lxml import html

data = """
    <breakfast_menu>
        <food>
            <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$5.95</price>
            <description>
                <taste>good</taste>
                <sight>bad</sight>
            </description>
            <calories>650</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$7.95</price>
            <description>
                <taste>bad</taste>
                <sight>bad</sight>
            </description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$8.95</price>
            <description>
                <taste>good</taste>
                <sight>good</sight>
            </description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>French Toast</name>
            <price>$4.50</price>
            <description>
                <taste>good</taste>
                <sight>bad</sight>
            </description>
            <calories>600</calories>
        </food>
    """

tree = html.fromstring(data)
tastes = tree.xpath("//taste")
for taste in tastes:
    foodparent = taste.getparent().getparent()
    name = foodparent.xpath("name")[0].text 
    if taste.text == "good":
        price = foodparent.xpath("price")[0].text
        print "%s: %s" % (name, price)
    else:
        print "%s: %s" % (name, "Taste is bad, yuck.")
```

**Result:**

```
Belgian Waffles: $5.95
Strawberry Belgian Waffles: Taste is bad, yuck.
Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles: $8.95
French Toast: $4.50
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Say that your xml is stored in a string variable called `xml_string`, so using `ElementTree` and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/), you can select all the *food* elements that contains a *description* element with a *taste* element with a value of "good". Then, you can extract whatever information you want from those *food* elements.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)

food_elements = tree.findall('.//food/description[taste="good"]/..')
prices = [(food.find('name').text, food.find('price').text) for food in food_elements]
print(prices)
```

Prints out:

```
[('Belgian Waffles', '$5.95'), ('Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles', '$8.95'), ('French Toast', '$4.50')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('breakfast.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for food in root.findall('food'):
    if food.find('description').find('taste').text == 'good':
        price = food.find('price').text
        print "found good food:{0} at price {1}".format(food.find('name').text, price)
```

Result:

```
found good food:Belgian Waffles at price $5.95
found good food:Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles at price $8.95
found good food:French Toast at price $4.50
```

Edit: I also had to fix your xml as you were missing the closing  tag